# My favicon.ico doesn't seem to be getting published

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using VS2010 and IIS7. When I test locally I see the favicon.ico but remotely it seems not to be published. Is there some trick to making this happen. When I go on my web site I get 404 file not found for the file but I can see it locally and its sitting at the root level next to my robots.txt.  The difference is that the robots.txt gets published.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select favicon.ico in the Solution Explorer, press `alt-enter` to view its properties, then select *Content* under Build Action.

If the icon is greyed out, it's likely it has not been included in your project. Right-click on the file and select *Include in Project*.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do. But all is see are "Custom Tool", "Custome Tool Namespace", "File Name" and "Full path". No Build action option as for the robots.txt.  "Build Action" and "copy to output directory" don't exist as options on the properties. Very strange ..

Comment: Is the favicon.ico icon whited-out? Right-click it and select `Include in Project`.

Comment: My guess is that your favicon.ico file isn't included in your .csproj project file definition, even though the file is sitting in part of the folder structure that your project is using.  Normally you wouldn't see these files, but at the top of your Solution Explorer you can click a small icon to "show all files" which does just that, showing all files whether they're registered with your project or not.  Right click on the favicon.ico file and select "include in project."  Then when you right click it again and choose Properties, you should see the rest of the options that Paperjam mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. You're correct and it was not included in the project.